# Divide Multideminsional Array by key values php and outputing to form

Tags: php, arrays, html, multidimensional-array

I have a query that cannot be edited that outputs an array on an if statement and it outputs to a printable html page (as a table with page breaks) based on the value of a variable, but I need to further dived the array so that it outputs multiple sheets with pages breaks, based on the number of different values of a key.

```
if($Guide=='N'){
$decisionN[$j] = array(
   'Qty'=>$Qty ,
'Comments'=>$Notes,
'Location'=>$Location,
'GuideRef'=>$GuideRef ,  
                     );
$j++; 
    }
```

and then

```
<?php
}
if ($decisionN){
$Guide2="N"
    ?>
```

```
&nbsp;&nbsp; Checkin for <?php echo $Guide2;?>
<!--</div>-->
```

```
    <table class="tablesorter" id="guides" style="border: 1px solid black;">

        <thead>
            <tr>

              <!--<th style="width: 15px;">PO</th> -->
                <th style="width: 5px;">Qty</th>
                <th style="width: 15px;">COMMENTS</th>
                <th style="width: 10px;">LOCATION</th>
                <th style="width: 12px;">GUIDEREF</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

                <?php foreach($decisionN as $v){
                     echo "<tr>";
                  foreach($v as $vv){
                     echo "<td>{$vv}</td>";
                }
                    echo "<tr>";
}

 ?> </tbody><tfoot> </tfoot> </table></div> </div> <footer>Checkin List</footer>
```

works perfect and breaks after footer for next value of guide, what i need is to divide $decisionN into differnet arrays based on $GuideRef ( might be 10 different values of $GuideRef and each $GuideRef could have 100 "rows") I tried a couple different foreach statements but got nothing thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you need.

You have an array like this:

```
[
    [
        'Qty'=>$Qty,
        'Location'=>$Location,
        'GuideRef'=>$GuideRef,

    ],
    [
        'Qty'=>$Qty2,
        'Location'=>$Location2,
        'GuideRef'=>$GuideRef,
    ],
    [
        'Qty'=>$Qty3,
        'Location'=>$Location3,
        'GuideRef'=>$GuideRef2,
    ],
]
```

... but you want it like this

```
[
    'guideref1' => [
        [
            'Qty'=>$Qty,
            'Location'=>$Location,
        ],
        [
            'Qty'=>$Qty2,
            'Location'=>$Location2,
        ]
    ],
    'guideref2' => [
        [
            'Qty'=>$Qty3,
            'Location'=>$Location3,
        ]
     ]
]
```

What you should do is:

In your initial loop (the one where you generate the array), on each iteration, check if you've already generated an sub-array for key "guiderefX", if you did then push to it, otherwise, create an empty sub-array with key "guiderefX" and then push inside it.

The above will allow you to create "groups" by "guideref" when you display the table.

Here's an example in which I group the array below, by color:

```
<?php
    $arr = [
        [
            'color' =>  'yellow',
            'name' => 'apple'
        ],
        [
            'color' =>  'yellow',
            'name' => 'lemon'
        ],
        [
            'color' =>  'green',
            'name' => 'watermelon'
        ]
    ];

    $length = count($arr);
    $new_arr = [];
    for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) { 
        if(!isset($new_arr[ $arr[$i]['color'] ])) {
            $new_arr[ $arr[$i]['color'] ] = [];
        }
        array_push( $new_arr[ $arr[$i]['color'] ], $arr[$i]);
    }
```

I hope I understood what you needed...